# Markers not rendering on 3d globe

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am currently working on a project where I'm rendering a 3D globe on the web. This globe is supposed to feature interactive markers at various points of interest. These markers are designed to be clickable by the user. The primary functionality I intend for these markers is that upon clicking, they should trigger an overlay to appear. This overlay can display additional information and can be positioned either on top of the current screen, overlaying the globe itself, or on one side of the screen, such as the right or left margin, to complement the visual representation provided by the globe.

Initially, my implementation was functioning as expected. The markers were appearing on the globe, and clicking on them would successfully bring up the overlay with the intended information displayed in the manner I had designed.
However, I've recently encountered a significant issue where the markers are no longer appearing on the globe. This problem has arisen unexpectedly, as I have not made any conscious changes to the parts of my code that manage the rendering of these markers or their associated click events. The absence of these markers directly impacts the usability and functionality of the globe, preventing users from accessing the detailed information these markers are meant to reveal.

I am seeking advice or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue. Specifically, I'm interested in understanding common reasons why such markers might fail to appear in a 3D rendering context and how I might go about debugging this problem. Moreover, I would appreciate guidance on best practices for ensuring that interactive elements like these markers remain robust and functional across updates to the code or the underlying libraries/frameworks I might be using.

Could anyone provide insights into why these markers have disappeared and how I might resolve this issue to restore the full functionality of my 3D globe project?

```
// earthindex.js
import React from 'react';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { MarkerProvider } from './MarkerContext';
import Globe from './Globe';
import { OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei';

const handleMarkerClick = (marker) => {
  console.log("Marker clicked:", marker);
  // Add additional logic here as needed
};
export function Earth() {
  // Marker data including image URLs
  const markers = [
    { lat: 40.7128, lon: -74.0060, name: 'New York', imageUrl: 'https://placehold.co/100' },
    { lat: 40.7128, lon: -74.0060, name: 'New York', imageUrl: 'https://placehold.co/100' },
    { lat: 40.7128, lon: -74.0060, name: 'New York', imageUrl: 'https://placehold.co/100' },
    // Add more markers as needed
  ];

  return (
    <MarkerProvider>
      
        <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
        <directionalLight color="#ffffff" intensity={2} position={[1, -5, 5]} castShadow />
        <Globe markers={markers} onMarkerClick={(marker) => handleMarkerClick(marker)}/>
        <OrbitControls enableZoom={false} enablePan={true} enableRotate={true} />
      
    </MarkerProvider>
  );
}
```

```
// earthindex.js
import React from 'react';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { MarkerProvider } from './MarkerContext';
import Globe from './Globe';
import { OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei';

const handleMarkerClick = (marker) => {
  console.log("Marker clicked:", marker);
  // Add additional logic here as needed
};
export function Earth() {
  // Marker data including image URLs
  const markers = [
    { lat: 40.7128, lon: -74.0060, name: 'New York', imageUrl: 'https://placehold.co/100' },
    { lat: 40.7128, lon: -74.0060, name: 'New York', imageUrl: 'https://placehold.co/100' },
    { lat: 40.7128, lon: -74.0060, name: 'New York', imageUrl: 'https://placehold.co/100' },
    // Add more markers as needed
  ];

  return (
    <MarkerProvider>
      
        <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
        <directionalLight color="#ffffff" intensity={2} position={[1, -5, 5]} castShadow />
        <Globe markers={markers} onMarkerClick={(marker) => handleMarkerClick(marker)}/>
        <OrbitControls enableZoom={false} enablePan={true} enableRotate={true} />
      
    </MarkerProvider>
  );
}
```

```
//globe.js
import React from 'react';
import useTextureLoader from './useTextureLoader';
import { useMarker } from './MarkerContext'; // Assuming Marker is its own component
import colorMap from '../../assets/textures/8k_earth_daymap.jpg';

function Globe({ markers }) {
  // Load the texture using the custom hook
  const earthTexture = useTextureLoader(colorMap);

  return (
    <mesh receiveShadow>
      <sphereGeometry args={[2, 32, 32]} />
      {/* Apply the texture to the material */}
      <meshStandardMaterial map={earthTexture} />
      {markers.map((marker) => (
        <mesh key={marker.id} position={marker.position}>
          <sphereGeometry args={[0.1, 32, 32]} />
          <meshStandardMaterial color="red" />
          {/* Additional marker logic */}
        </mesh>
      ))}
    </mesh>
  );
}

export default Globe;
```

Tried mapping markers on globe and setting the state on markercontext